# Callbacks() is not a function

Tags: jquery

```
 var foo = function( value ) {
          alert( "foo: " + value );
        };

        // Another function to also be added to the list
        var bar = function( value ) {
          alerts( "bar: " + value );
        };

        var callbacks = $.Callbacks();
```

When i am trying to run above code in firefox browser it's showing me that $.Callbacks() is not a function.

Comment: Have you included the jQuery library in your code?

Comment: it works for me http://jsbin.com/AWOHAnI/1/edit

Comment: Check, `if ( typeof $.fn.Callbacks !== 'undefined' )` or `typeof $.fn.Callbacks` - But as @Coulton mentions, sounds very very much like no jQuery included ;]

Comment: Maybe your code is executed when jQuery is not yet loaded?

Comment: please suggest any answer....

Comment: There's nothing in the code you've posted that allows us to figure out why it's not working for you.

Comment: You've got 3 above?! What version of JQuery are you using? where's the HTML that loads jquery?

Comment: Are other jQuery functions working?

Comment: show how and where u have added jquery library and where are u using above code

Comment: @harshagarwal please double check your question, use this one http://jsbin.com/aJokUgA/1/edit from sansix. It seems to work well for me on firefox nightly.
If we cannot reproduce the error, we cannot help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be your code is executed before your jquery loaded. please call the function in document.ready so that it will be called only when full page is loaded.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var foo = function( value ) {
          alert( "foo: " + value );
        };

        // Another function to also be added to the list
        var bar = function( value ) {
          alerts( "bar: " + value );
        };

        var callbacks = $.Callbacks();

callbacks.add(foo);
callbacks.fire("test");
}
```

Comment: He's not accessing the DOM, why would he need to wrap it in a DOM ready function?